# How do we prove this equality involving pseudoinverse?

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

Given a rectangular matrix $A$, how do we prove that $A^{\dagger} \left(A^{\dagger}\right)^{H} = \left(A^{H}A\right)^{-1}$, where $A^{\dagger} = \left(A^{H}A\right)^{-1}A^{H}$ is the right pseudo inverse operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just substitute the definition in $A^\dagger(A^\dagger)^H$ using $(XY)^H=Y^HX^H$, and that $A^HA$ is self-adjoint hence so is its inverse.

Comment: Had to look up the definition of the self-adjoint property. Makes sense now.